# Docker Image from Build Directory vs Source directory

Tags: docker

Most of the DockerFiles seem to be generating the image from the source code directory. Is there a reason why this is done?

For example, If I run the build commands in a windows machine and copy the dist folder into a linux machine and run as per Option 2, isn't it supposed to work?

**Option 1** - Docker file (from source directory)

```
FROM node:latest as build    
WORKDIR /usr/local/app    
COPY ./ /usr/local/app/    
RUN npm install    
RUN npm run build    
FROM nginx:latest    
COPY --from=build /usr/local/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html    
EXPOSE 80
```

**Option 2** - Dockerfile from build output

```
FROM nginx:latest    
COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html    
EXPOSE 80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first form uses a Docker [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).  This has the specific advantage of not depending on any particular tools being installed on the host system.  I'd consider this path:

- If you have a clustered CI system, it can be much easier to run the build in a container than to try to get the required tools manually installed on every worker system.
- If you're working in a compiled language (C, Go, Rust, ...), you can consistently use Linux containers even if developers use a different host OS.
- If you need to do extra work to set up the build system, like installing extra C development packages.
- If you need a really exact version of the language runtime for whatever reason.

The second path depends on having the toolchain available outside the container environment.  That's not necessarily a problem; most front-end developers will probably have Node installed anyways.  I'd consider this path:

- If the result of the build is extremely portable across environments (compiled HTML and Javascript; Java `.jar` files; interpreted text-format Python or Ruby scripting code).
- If there aren't big differences in different versions of the language runtime itself to produce the build.  (Does your Webpack build do anything different on Node 8, 10, 12, or 14?)
- If the build system is something that's easy to install, or preinstalled in most host environments.  (Most Linux and MacOS systems have Python, for example.)
- If a host build system can do incremental builds or otherwise run much faster than a clean-slate container build.

For what you show, with a simple front-end application that's compiled to static files, your second form is just fine.  If you look at SO Java questions they almost universally `COPY` a prebuilt `.jar` file into an image, without including a build chain.

Comment: The answer makes perfect sense. Thank you!